# making Arithmetic in verilog (sign extension) edited

Tags: math, verilog, shift, vivado, sign-extension

(edited) i'm working on the verilog Arithmetic project and i got stuck on the sign extension part(assuming this is the problem). i have 4bit input A, B and should have 8 bit output. for some of the process(sum, sub...) i need to use sign extend to make the 8bit output. so for the body of arithmetic, i have this code. this is half of the code. i didn't include the half part cuz it's just long..

```
module arithmetic(A, B, AN0, DP, sum, sub, mult, div, comp, shiftLeft, 
shiftRight, signExtend);

   input signed [3:0] A, B;

   output [7:0] sum, sub, mult, div, comp, shiftLeft, shiftRight, 
   signExtend;

   output AN0, DP;

   //sum
   reg [4:0] qsum;   
   always@ (A, B)
      qsum = A+B;

   assign sum = {{3{qsum[4]}},qsum};

   //sub
   reg [4:0] qsub;

   always@ (A, B)
      qsub = A-B;

   assign sub = {{3{qsub[4]}},qsub};

   //mult
   reg [7:0] qmult;
   always@ (A, B)
      qmult = A * B;

   assign mult = qmult;
```

and when i checked my simulation, it doesn't have any values but Z, and Xs. it doesn't even show any input values. why is that happening?? thank you

(edited) this is my test bench code. there are 8 operations(sum, subtract, multiply, division, comparator, shiftleft, shiftright, sign extension)

```
module lap3_top_tb();
reg signed [3:0] A, B;
reg [2:0] Operation;
wire [7:0] Result;
wire DP, AN0;

lab3_top ulap3_top(
  .A(A),
  .B(B),
  .Operation(Operation),
  .Result(Result),
  .DP(DP),
  .AN0(AN0)
);

initial begin
   A = 6; B = 7; Operation = 0;
   #20;
   A = -6; B = -7; Operation = 0;
   #20;      
   A = 6; B = 7; Operation = 1;
   #20;
   A = -6; B = -7; Operation = 1;
   #20;
   A = 6; B = 7; Operation = 2;
   #20;
   A = -6; B = 7; Operation = 2;
   #20;
   A = 7; B = 4; Operation = 3;
   #20;
   A = 7; B = 0; Operation = 3;
   #20;
   A = 6; B = 7; Operation = 4;
   #20;
   A = -6; B = -7; Operation = 4;
   #20;
   A = 1; B = 6; Operation = 5;
   #20;
   A = 1; B = -6; Operation = 5;
   #20;
   A = 1; B = 6; Operation = 6;
   #20;
   A = 1; B = -6; Operation = 6;
   #20;
   A = 6; B = 0; Operation = 7;
   #20;
   A = -5; B = 0; Operation = 7;
   #20;
end

endmodule
```

the lap3_top file is here. (mux_8_1 will pick the output and out thru Result. if you need code, let me know! but i think mux works fine)

```
module lap3_top(A, B, Operation, Result, AN0, DP);
   input signed [3:0] A, B;
   input [2:0] Operation;
   output AN0, DP;

   output [7:0] Result;
   wire a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;

   arithmetic uarithmetic(
   .A(A), 
   .B(B), 
   .AN0(AN0), 
   .DP(DP), 
   .sum(a), 
   .sub(b), 
   .mult(c), 
   .div(d), 
   .comp(e), 
   .shiftLeft(f), 
   .shiftRight(g), 
   .signExtend(h)
   );

   mux_8_1 umux8_1(
   .A(a), 
   .B(b), 
   .C(c), 
   .D(d), 
   .E(e), 
   .F(f), 
   .G(g), 
   .H(h), 
   .Operation(Operation), 
   .Result(Result)
   );

endmodule
```

thank you so much guys!

Comment: Hello Jake, could you share some of your testbench code?

Comment: Could you also post your `lab3_top` module, that see all connections from the `testbench` to the `sum` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to simulate your code and found a following mistake in your code: when you instantiation top module in the testbench module you use `lab3_top ulap3_top(...);` la**b**3_top name of module, but module which would you like to has another name `module lap3_top(...);` la**p**3_top.

I changed the name and everything works well (on waveform you can see `ZZ` state,
 because I haven't `mux_8_1` module in the code and few operation haven't description)[image]

P.S. By the way, I suppose that you use Vivado as you add this tag. And if that, there has a hint how to check errors like this (with different names in module and in instantiation or when you have some errors in module that it couldn't be compiled in library). If you expand all your modules in hierarchy​ you will find `?` sign in module where error is. [image]

Comment: @Jake I also added more information which I hope could help you in future work with Vivado